# Can I fit enough useful A / B testing data into 30MB or 100MB of Redis on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, ab-testing, abtest

Ok this question is admittedly coming from an interest in not spending money I don't have to. And I know it's hard to "estimate" this kind of thing. But maybe someone out there feels they have a confident ballpark figure they could offer.

I want to start doing A/B testing in my ruby on rails app hosted on heroku. I have several gems/libraries to choose from to implement the A/B tests.

[Split, the gem that seems to be most full-featured](https://github.com/splitrb/split) only uses a Redis data store, whereas others use a SQL store, but seem not as solid. I feel a bit gun-shy of using Redis, increasing the complexity of my stack, and possibly incurring $10 - $50 per month just for A/B testing.

The [Redis Cloud](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud) add-on offers 30MB on the free tier and 100MB at $10/mo. I'm having trouble visualizing what kind of usefulness I can get out of the free tier or the 100MB tier.

I'd rather not implement the A/B testing in my app (investing in a certain API / config setup), only to find that I can't afford it.

So to phrase my question in the (over) simplest way possible. How many months of data could I expect to be able to collect with 5-10 A/B tests on 30MB (and/or 100MB) of Redis?

Comment: I read Split's `README.md` and it seems that you don't have to use Redis. It's one of the options for recording which variants were presented to users. Another option is using cookies. Does your setup require you to use Redis? Or would cookies work?

Comment: As far as I can tell you may be reading this wrong. The library will need a persistent data store to collect data over an indefinite period. This is different from the temporary data that tracks user sessions. The latter has several options, but the form seems to be "Split uses redis as a datastore."